# Should I Use RoboGuice or other Dependency Injection Frameworks?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, roboguice

I heard from a friend that Coading gets a lot Easier and simpler with [**RoboGuice**](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice). But I found [Official document of Android](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#DependencyInjection) when I was reading [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-android-part-7-useful-tools/). In its **2nd Point** the Author said:

> Official document of Android suggests to avoid dependency injection
>   frameworks like Guice or RoboGuice, reason being is it’s a reflection
>   based library and it creates overheads at run time. Even it tends to
>   perform a lot of process initialization by scanning your code for
>   annotations, which can require significant amounts of your code to be
>   mapped into RAM even though you don’t need it. (Here I would say we
>   can use Android annotation library because it creates duplicate copy
>   of annotated classes so it won’t create any overhead at runtime but at
>   compile time.)

So Should I use it or Not? Any Help Will Be Appretiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's getting easier but as you read in the official document like you stated above that kind of dependency injection can slow down your app performance because it depends on [Java's Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).
But not all dependency injection are using Reflection like [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) and [Dagger 2](http://google.github.io/dagger/) so it won't affect your app performance.

Example of Butterknife usage :

```
class ButterknifeActivity extends Activity {
  @Bind(R.id.title) TextView title;
  @Bind(R.id.logo) ImageView logo;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
  }
}
```

With Butterknife you don't need to call findViewById and cast it, instead the library will do that for you.

Comment: hmmm... k thanks... I will give it a try...